# Execution time exceeds on Laravel Notification to mailtrap.io

Tags: laravel, notifications

I am trying to send email-notification form my Laravel App to my inbox at mailtrap.io

I selected laravle 9+ in settings of my Inbox at mailtrap.io and copied the variables and pasted it to my project .env file.

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxx
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

created the notification "WelcomeNotification" and the used it in HomeController like this.

```
 public function index(){
    $user = User::find(1);
    Notification::send($user, new WelcomeNotification);;
    // $user->notify(new WelcomeNotification);
    return view('welcome');
}
```

it throws error `Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded`

I've tried it on port 25, 465 and 587 but none worked and throws another errors.

Note: I am using Laravel 10.24

Comment: That could be anything not just related to mailtrap .. If you have any instruction in the `WelcomeNotification` .. if not just try to change the port to `465` or `587`

Comment: @PsyLogic on port 465 it throws another error: Connection could not be established with host "ssl://sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io:465": stream_socket_client(): SSL: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Comment: @PsyLogic:- and on port 587 it throws error: Expected response code "220" but got code "421", with message "421 Cannot connect to SMTP server 3.219.2.182 (3.219.2.182:587), connect error 10060".

Comment: There is nothing else in the project. this is the only controller and I'm just testing notification.  I haven't changed anything in the `WelcomNotification`

Comment: I think you have to clear the cache .. or exec this cmd: `php artisan optimize:clear`
It could be a cached config there or something ..  keep the port as it `2525`

Comment: @PsyLogic:- Already done with no success.

Comment: You might have made multiple (GET/POST) Request within 60 seconds. Some suggest updating the `max_execution_time` in php.ini file

Comment: No. I' have just load the home page.